# (EXCEL) When using a Pivot Table to create a Line Chart, is there a way to restrict the amount of dates shown after Showing Items with No Data?

Tags: excel, date, charts, pivot-table

Is it possible to create a pivot table line chart that shows all dates, regardless of if there is data for them, by day, but only within a specific range?

Let's say I have the following data set that I'd like to summarize in a Line Chart by day (not by month) to show how many enrollments are coming over Q1.

[Example Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWcjc.png)

I can easily summarize this into a Pivot Table by day, with a rolling total to show increase over time:

[Running Total Pivot Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UD5d1.png)

However, when you put this in a line chart, it does not include any of the dates where no enrollments took place:

[Running Total Pivot Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hmxs3.png)

I'd like to show change over the entire Quarter, so I need those "blank" dates to be in there.  In the Pivot Table Field Settings, under "Layout & Print", I can select "Show items with no data", which then adds in all of the missing dates.  HOWEVER, it adds them for the entire year (and before/after 2023):

[Pivot Chart All Dates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08aZ1.png)

When I use any of the default Date Filter options, it only filters the data, and not the displayed date values.  It would seem the only way I can actually remove Quarters 2-4 would be by manually unchecking each of those dates in the Pivot Table field filter.  Is there some other way I can show all dates within Jan-Mar without needing to uncheck 280 boxes?  Do I just need to restructure my original data?